# Installing Java JDK in busybox in an LXC container - java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Tags: software-installation, java, busybox, lxc

In a web application I'm developing, users will be able to upload java code and I will need to compile and run that. For security reasons, I'd like to that inside an LXC container, and for footprint reasons I'd like that to be a busybox. So, I created a busybox container successfully with:

```
lxc-create -n my-box -t busybox
```

It's up and running fine. Then, I downloaded jdk-8u31-linux-i586.rpm from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and ran `rpm -i jdk-8u31-linux-i586.rpm`, which returned no output but created `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31` which all looks good.

However, when I go to `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin` and run `./javac -version`, I get:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin # ./javac -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

I figured this may be because of the classpath or java_home not being the right setting, so, I created a `/etc/profile`:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31
CLASSPATH=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31/lib
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export CLASSPATH
export PATH
```

This works fine, when I echo the variables they have the values I set to them. However, the problem with `javac` persists. `java` has the exact same output.

What did I miss here?

The host system is Ubuntu Server 14.04. I have tried also the x64 version, with the same result.

Comment: It is possible the heap is too small on your container or a 32/64-bit issue.

Comment: @Ketan thank you for your help - as it turned out the problem seems to have been a different one though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14480193/1544337): I still had to unpack the *.pack files from the lib and jre/lib folders in the java installation. `unpack200`, the program used to unpack *.pack files to .jar files isn't available in busybox, but it's shipped with java.